# Gauss divergence theorem, left hand side is not equal to the right hand side?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

We all know that Gauss divergence theorem says:

$$\iint_{dK} F \cdot N dS = \iiint_K div F dV..... (1) $$

And I have a question about this. I have a problem who's says that $f(x,y,z) = (x^3, y^3, z^3)$ and $K = {(x,y,z): x^2 + y^2 \le z^2, z \in [0,1]}.$

---

a) The left hand side in equation (1) doesn't matter, since we are dealing with 3 different variables in the $dS$ ? Should it always be 2 variables?

b) The interval in $z$ does it mean that the normal, is BOTH N=(0,0,1) or N=(0,0,-1) ?

I decided to calculate it like this:

$$\int_{dK} (x^3+y^3+z^3) dxdydz = \int_0^{2 \pi} \int_0^z (r^3(\cos^3 \theta+ \sin^3 \theta) + rz^3) dr d\theta d\phi$$ BUT that dosen't make since since I have all the three $r, \theta, \phi$!! How *COULD* I even solve this?

Okey.. So let's see the right hand side..

$$\iiint_K div F dV = 3 \iiint (x^2+y^2+z^2) dxdydz = 3 \int_0^1  \int_0^z \int_0^{2\pi} (r^2 + z^2) rdrdz$$

c) But that is wrong right?

I'm just so confused.. How should it be done? **BOTH** sides? (not just one) if someone kindly would show me?

Comment: before i even try to answer this question, can you imagine what the volume K looks like geometrically? WhT about its Boundary?

Comment: @peek-a-boo It is a cone, with the tip facing down wards. Like a V but it has a lid.. do you know what I mean?

Comment: .. And $N=(0,0,1)$ Beauce of that, and $\iint_{Y_1} (x^3,y^3,z^3) \cdot (0,0,1) dS = \iint_{Y_1} z^3 dS$ where $Y_1$ represent the lid of the cone. And since the lid is a circle: $r \in [0,z]$ and $\theta \in [0,2 \pi]$ right?

Comment: almost right. the lid is a circle of radius $1$. now what about the cuved part of the cone?

Comment: @peek-a-boo but the circle of radius, what do you mean there? the size of a radius can be how long? but I guess mine is 1 then since since x^2+y^2 \le z^2?.. And the curved part of the cone.. is that z \in [0,1] ?